# Does ctx need to be freed and re-newed for multi-HMACs

Tags: openssl, hmac

Using the EVP_MAC functions, if I am performing multiple MACs do I need to free and new the ctx for each MAC or is the init function sufficient.

Can I

EVP_MAC_CTX_new,

multipe EVP_MAC_init, EVP_MAC_update, EVP_MAC_final,

EVP_MAC_CTX_free

or do I need to

EVP_MAC_CTX_new, EVP_MAC_init, EVP_MAC_update, EVP_MAC_final, EVP_MAC_CTX_free,
for each hmac?

Comment: You should be able to reuse the context repeatedly, so long as it is never used *concurrently* for multiple HMACs (or worse, multiple HMACs on multiple threads). the Init of the Init/Update/Final trio should initialize the context back to start-state based on the provided key and parameter stack.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  I was hoping that was the case.